# What ASTM standard would be appropriate for testing the breaking strength of nylon ropes

Tags: standards, product-testing, failure-analysis

[ASTM D4268-93](https://www.astm.org/Standards/D4268.htm) would appear to be the relevant testing standard, but this was withdrawn in 2002 and is no longer active. Is there a current standard?

Answer (score 2):

Go directly to the ASTM site. I put "nylon rope" in search and it said there were 154 possibilities.

Comment: I already did that, but didn't find any that seemed applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [ASTM A931 - 18  Standard Test Method for Tension Testing of Wire Ropes and Strand](https://www.astm.org/Standards/A931.htm)

There are others  closely related but not exactly the same.

- ASTM F3410 - 19  Standard Test Method for Testing Fiber Rope Used in Water Sports
- ISO 3108:2017(en), Steel wire ropes — Test method

Comment: The appropriate ISO standards appears to be ISO 2307:2019(en), but I'm looking for an ASTM option. Unfortunately, my application is not water sports or F3410 would probably be applicable.